# Set a basic Java option on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

I need to add `-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES="*"` to my tomcat in my `catalina.bat` file

```
rem Register custom URL handlers
rem Do this here so custom URL handles (specifically 'war:...') can be used in the security policy
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*"
```

But I'm still getting this error

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Forbidden class
>   mypackage.Something! This class
>   is not trusted to be serialized as ObjectMessage payload. Please take
>   a look at http://activemq.apache.org/objectmessage.html for more
>   information on how to configure trusted classes.

[If I set this property in the JVM Arguments on Eclipse Tomcat Server it works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqQVt.png)

So I'm guessing this is not setting the property.
What's the problem?

PS: I start tomcat with `catalina.bat run`

Answer (score 1):

Follow [Tomcat configuration recommendations](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E40518_01/integrator.311/integrator_install/src/cli_ldi_server_config.html)

Update `setenv.bat` with adding the property to `JAVA_OPTS`

> It is recommended that you create a file named setenv.bat (Windows) or setenv.sh (Linux) and place it in the Tomcat bin directory. With this file (which is run by the catalina.bat and catalina.sh scripts), you can change the following Tomcat environment settings with the JAVA_OPTS variable: